# The type '***' is not assignable to service '***' in Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I am now doing a dynamic query in my project by using System.Linq.Dynamic. I use Autofac as my default IOC container. But Now I get a problem on registering generic components, here is my code :

the interface:

```
public interface IDynamicQuery
{
    IQueryable<T> CreateDynamicQuery<T>(string propertyName, string propertyValue, Expression<Func<T, bool>> where) where T:class;
}
```

the class:

```
public class DynamicQuery :IDynamicQuery
{
    public DynamicQuery(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    private  readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public IQueryable<T> CreateDynamicQuery<T>(string propertyName, string propertyValue, Expression<Func<T, bool>> where) where T:class
    {
        var appRepository = unitOfWork.Repository<T>();

        IQueryable<T> queryResult = null;
        if (propertyName.Contains('$'))  
            propertyName = propertyName.Replace('$', '.');
        queryResult = appRepository.GetMany(where).Where("" + propertyName + ".Contains(\"" + propertyValue + "\")");
        return queryResult;
    }
}
```

Then I register them in the application start entry:

```
builder.RegisterType<IDynamicQuery>().As<DynamicQuery>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

But When I start up my project based on MVC 4, it throws me an exception like :

> ```
>  The type 'TinyFrame.Framework.Query.IDynamicQuery' is not assignable to service 'TinyFrame.Framework.Query.DynamicQuery'.
> ```

the Exception throws at : `var container = builder.Build();`

I know how to register a generic class in autofac, but I don't know how to register above class I raised, anyone can help me on this? I am a new comer to autofac, thx in advice.

Comment: You have it the wrong way round. An `IDynamicQuery` is not a `DynamicQuery` but a `DynamicQuery` IS an `IDynamicQuery`.

Comment: @Aron Oh my god, how careless of me..... I had a bad sleep last night. thx for advice.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

@CharlieShi I had the same problem and I noticed that I was forgetting to add inheritance to my class. But in your case, try this:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<DynamicQuery>().As<IDynamicQuery>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

reverse the interface with the class!

Comment: D'oh. I'd forgotten to add the interface to my class too. It's is Friday, so that's my excuse.

Comment: @RichS hahaha, it's happen guy!

Comment: THIS part of your comment really helped me!! --> I was forgetting to add inheritance

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I had reversed the order in which the interface and the classes are to be mentioned:

```
builder.RegisterType<CONCRETE_CLASS>().As<INTERFACE>();
```

Answer (score 8):

This can be done if you forget to add the Interface to your class.

```
builder.RegisterType<People>().As<IPeople>();
```

This will cause the error

```
public class People
```

This will resolve it

```
public class People : IPeople
```

Comment: This was my issue

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue.  It's funny how you can miss little things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the **complete assembly** with autofac container like this way:

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(
            typeof(YourClass).Assembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

In your case, if you want to register the **perticular type** only, then just use the following:

```
builder.RegisterType<DynamicQuery>()
             .As<IDynamicQuery>()
             .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

You can set the lifetime according to your business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you try to map interface on implementation, just swap IDynamicQuery and DynamicQuery. And don't forget to make a rebuild.

It should be like:

```
builder.RegisterType<DynamicQuery>().As<IDynamicQuery>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem but the cause was different in my case. I didn't see that I was registering the same type twice.  I find this error message is misleading.